# Accessing class members in c++

Tags: c++, class-members

I got back coding in C++ after a long while and was wondering if there is a way to access data member of a class quickly for manipulation.

Assume a case where you have like 10 data members in a class which overloads a bunch of operators (thought of this while overloading operator=). Now you would want to add/subtract a few data members to the class.
Is there a generic way to accomplish this without having to go to individual functions and change them? I'm thinking of a possibility of running through all the members of a class in a kind of loop construct.

Comment: so you want to apply the same operation to a set of variables which may change? Are they all the same type?

Comment: This is a vague description. Even a pseudo-code can clarify what you want to accomplish.

Comment: If I understand you correctly then no. C++ doesn't have support for that kind of reflection. If you provide an example, someone might have an elegant solution vor your particular case.

Comment: were you thinking something along [these lines](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/853f9f56d8946667), OP? This would allow you to loop over every element in a specified list. Unless you're willing to use `boost::any` you'll have to stick with references to a single type though.

Comment: @jaggedSpire, no the idea is to reduce the amount of change to the source code... The class object is not yet created and the class has a bunch of data members. Now while defining an operator= overload, if you would add more data member, you would have to manually go the method and change the source code.. so I'm thinking of a way to avoid by allowing access to these members within the a method to iterate over them and not change what the members originally are

Comment: @AnandRamesh ...not the way I just posted. With the way I posted, you maintain a single list of members, and just change that when you add or remove members of your class. At any rate from your comments on πάντα ῥεῖ's answer you need to deal with different types, so Horstling's answer is most likely applicable to you, since it lets you specify every element you want to alter in a single location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is no built-in reflection in C++ (yet), you have to list all your members somewhere. One way to save you from doing this over and over again is to define a `for_each_member` method which passes every member to some functor:

```
template <class F>
void for_each_member(F f);
```

Now you can easily apply arbitrary operations to all your members, and you only have to maintain one listing of members per class.

Running example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c813fc73c5519ee0

If you want to perform different actions for different subsets of member, you have to find a way to separate these apart. You could do this by type (as shown in the example) or you could additionally pass some kind of identifier to your functor in `for_each_member`.

Here I use a macro to pass both the member and its name to the functor: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a59c027e25c33fb

Comment: Don't be shy to post more code in your question. That would be easier to read fro future research. Have the live sample links for improvement.

Comment: Gets me very close to what I'm looking for.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm thinking of a possibility of running through all the members of a class in a kind of loop construct.

No, such isn't possible in general, since *standard C++* doesn't have any runtime reflection mechanism, that allows you to access class members by symbolic information.

---

What you can do of course is something to keep your *class member variable* values in a kind of `std::map<std::string,T>` dictionary, and access these with symbolic keys (replacing the actual class member variables of course).

But that would require the value type to be

- all of the same type
- something like [`std::experimental::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/any)

Comment: I didn't know about `std::any` so thats awesome, this is likely a user XY problem though.

Comment: Ya I thought of something similar. The essential problem is that class members can be of different types. That's what made a construct like "struct" useful during early days of programming. Need a solution for which is generic enough to suit all data members without a need to modify or place them a container.